# Integrating the absolute of the cosine

Tags: integration

For some reason, I do not understand when computing the the integral of |cos(x)|
from -pi to -pi/2 gives 1. When i compute it i get -1. There must be something I haven't understood.

Comment: If you show us your working, we may be able to see where you have gone wrong.

Comment: What I did so far was I know that |cos(x)| when x is [-pi,-pi/2], therefore i have -cos(x). So in my opinion i just integrate over -cos(x) from -pi to -pi/2.

Comment: Integrating $|\cos(x)|$ from $-\pi$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ doesn't give $1$. But it certain doesn't give $-1$ (integrating a positive function gives a positive value) either. So show us what you have done.

Comment: sorry i did a mistake, it is actually from -pi to -pi/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of integral can be computed by considering the domains on which the integrand takes the negative and positive of itself. So for instance:

$$|\cos(x)|=\begin{cases}\cos(x) & -\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2} \\ -\cos(x) & x \not\in[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]\end{cases}$$

Thus we can write our integral:

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|\cos(x)|\:\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\pi}^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}-\cos(x)\:\mathrm{d}x+\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(x)\:\mathrm{d}x = 1+2 = 3$$

Comment: sorry it is from -pi to -pi/2 which gives me 1

Comment: @franck That sounds like you have forgotten to include the minus sign in your definition of $|\cos(x)|$ in the domain $-\pi \leq x \leq -\frac{\pi}{2}$ then!

Answer (score 0):

For real $y,|y|=+y$ if $y\ge0$

and $=-y$ for $y<0$

Now $\cos x\ge0$ for $-\dfrac\pi2\le x\le\dfrac\pi2$

and $<0$ for $-\pi\le x\le-\dfrac\pi2$